# Multiple data values in ajax - going directly into exception

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi I am trying to put multiple values in the data with ajax but its going into the exception instead of success. It works ok with one data parameter.
I have written the data with correct syntax. Could you please look into this.

Comment: Remove the equal signs (=) from your data attributes.

Comment: What is the error message that the server is sending back?

Comment: Ajax request failed to post

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're getting an error because you're end point isn't responding correctly. Remove the dependency on jquery and just test your post with something like `curl` from your command line.

```
curl --data "recipeName=some_value&reprocessType=some_value" http://your-site.com/image/reprocessImage
```

If tat works confirm your data is setup correctly. Create the packet outside of `$.ajax` setup and console log it.

```
var data = {
  "recipeName=":l_sRecipeName,
  "reprocessType=": m_enumReprocessFrom
};
console.log(data);
$.ajax({
  data: data,
  ...
});
```

Comment: @thedeeno- I tried putting the data before the ajax call and pass everything as a parameter but doesnt work as well

Comment: It is still going to the exception.

Comment: I got my answer. I pass the three parameters as a single string using the parameters.